# How can I switch between the front and rear camera on Android in Qt/QML 6.5.2

Tags: android, qt, qml

I use the following code, inside the backFrontCameraClicked() function, I switch between cameras, but nothing happens.
The following code communicates with the camera on Android 13, inside videoOutput I have used pinchArea to zoom the camera using 2 fingers.

And how can I put a button to turn off the camera flash so that it does it for me.

```
CaptureSession {
        id:cpSession

        camera: Camera {
            id: camera
            focusMode: Camera.FocusModeAutoNear
            customFocusPoint: Qt.point(0.5, 0.5)
            whiteBalanceMode: Camera.WhiteBalanceManual
            //            colorTemperature: 5600
            zoomFactor: maximumZoomFactor
            //            cameraFormat.resolution: "1920*1080"
            active: false
            // cameraDevice.position: CameraDevice.FrontFace
            // cameraDevice: CameraDevice {
            //     position: CameraDevice.FrontFace
            // }

        }



        imageCapture : ImageCapture {
            id: imageCapture

            onImageCaptured: {
                console.log("------------ onImageCaptured ----------------")
            }

            onImageSaved: {
                console.log("------------ onImageSaved ----------------")
                prwCamera.imageSaved()
            }

            onImageAvailable: {
                console.log("------------ onImageAvailable ----------------")

            }

            onErrorStringChanged: {
                console.log("------------ onErrorOccurred ----------------")

            }

            onImageExposed: {
                console.log("------------ onImageExposed ----------------")

            }

            onPreviewChanged: {
                console.log("------------ onPreviewChanged ----------------")
            }

        }

        videoOutput: videoOutput
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: videoOutput
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: false
        fillMode: VideoOutput.PreserveAspectCrop
        focus: visible

        PinchArea{
            id: pinch
            anchors.fill: parent
            enabled: true

            onPinchStarted: {
                //                console.log("Started (pinch.scale) -->> " + pinch.scale)
                //                console.log("Started (pinch.angle) -->> " + pinch.angle)
                //                console.log("Started (pinch.center) -->> " + pinch.center)
                //                console.log("Started (pinch.point1) -->> " + pinch.point1)
                //                console.log("Started (pinch.pointCount) -->> " + pinch.pointCount)
                //                console.log("Started (pinch.rotation) -->> " + pinch.rotation)
            }

            onPinchUpdated: {

                var _MinScale = 1

                console.log("-----------------------------------------------")
                console.log("Updated (camera.minimumZoomFactor) -->> " + camera.minimumZoomFactor)
                console.log("Updated (camera.maximumZoomFactor) -->> " + camera.maximumZoomFactor)
                console.log("Updated (pinch.scale)              -->> " + pinch.scale)
                console.log("Updated (pinch.angle)              -->> " + pinch.angle)
                // console.log("Updated (pinch.center)             -->> " + pinch.center)
                // console.log("Updated (pinch.point1)             -->> " + pinch.point1)
                // console.log("Updated (pinch.pointCount)         -->> " + pinch.pointCount)
                // console.log("Updated (pinch.rotation)           -->> " + pinch.rotation)
                console.log("-----------------------------------------------")

                if(pinch.scale >= camera.minimumZoomFactor && pinch.scale <= camera.maximumZoomFactor)
                {
                    var _MaxScale = pinch.scale

                    // _lastScale = 4
                    // pinch.scale = 1
                    // 4 - 1 = 3
                    // _lastScale = pinch.scale - _lastScale
                    //

                    //                    _lastScale = pinch.scale - _lastScale

                    camera.zoomTo(pinch.scale, 0.5)
                    console.log("Updated (pinch.scale) -->> " + pinch.scale)
                    // console.log("Updated (_lastScale) -->> " + _lastScale)
                }
            }

            onPinchFinished: {
                //                if(pinch.scale >= camera.minimumZoomFactor && pinch.scale <= camera.maximumZoomFactor)
                //                {
                //                    _lastScale = pinch.scale // 4
                //                }


                //                if(_lastScale > pinch.scale)
                //                    _lastScale = _lastScale - pinch.scale
                //                else
                //                    _lastScale = pinch.scale - _lastScale

                //                console.log("Finished (pinch.scale) -->> " + pinch.scale)
                //                console.log("Finished (pinch.angle) -->> " + pinch.angle)
                //                console.log("Finished (pinch.center) -->> " + pinch.center)
                //                console.log("Finished (pinch.point1) -->> " + pinch.point1)
                //                console.log("Finished (pinch.pointCount) -->> " + pinch.pointCount)
                //                console.log("Finished (pinch.rotation) -->> " + pinch.rotation)
            }
        }
    }

function backFrontCameraClicked()
    {
        if ( appData._CameraBackFront )
            camera.cameraDevice.position = CameraDevice.BackFace
        else
            camera.cameraDevice.position = CameraDevice.FrontFace

        appData._CameraBackFront = !appData._CameraBackFront
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is that you are trying to update position property rather than whole cameraDevice. It's like you were trying change position of current camera (not the whole camera device)

You should use here [MediaDevices](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-mediadevices.html) type and get videoInputs (cameras). Then choose the correct camera from the list. Something like this:

```
MediaDevices {
    id: mediaDevices
}
function backFrontCameraClicked()
{
    var listOfCameras = mediaDevices.videoInputs
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfCameras.length; i++)  {
        if (listOfCameras[i].position === CameraDevice.BackFace)
            camera.cameraDevice = listOfCameras[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I turn the camera flash off and on manually?

Comment: Using [flashMode property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#flashMode-prop), so just set:

camera.cameraDevice.flashMode = Camera.FlashOn
or
camera.cameraDevice.flashMode = Camera.FlashOff

Or if you want to flash permanently - [torchMode property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#torchMode-prop):
camera.cameraDevice.torchMode = Camera.TorchOff
or
camera.cameraDevice.torchMode = Camera.TorchOn